# NSIS importing Databases

Tags: command-line, nsis

I want to develop an installer using NSIS which can import a .sql file to the MySql WorkBench 6.2

I use command

```
 SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite try  
File "${PROJECT_PATH}\IVMSClientEnterprise\ivms.sql"
 nsExec::Exec 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysql -u root -e "drop database ivms_db_clienta"'
  nsExec::Exec 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysql -u root -e "create database ivms_db_clienta"'
ReadRegStr $R0 HKCU "Software\IVMS_CLIENT_ENTERPRISE" "Location" 
 StrCpy $DatabasePath $R0
  nsExec::Exec ' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysql -u root -D ivms_db_clienta < D:\IVMS_client\ivms.sql'
```

but the last command which ll import the Database is not working..
can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Now I am Using [ nsExec::Exec '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "$PROGRAMFILES\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysql.exe" -u root -D "ivms_db_clienta" < "$INSTDIR\ivms_20_64_rl_channel_group.sql"']  But it is still not working..How can I check error returned by the function  nsExec::Exec?

Answer (score 1):

You should always quote the path to the executable: `nsExec::Exec '"c:\path\file.ext" param1 "pa r a m2 "'`

The other issue is that you are trying to use redirection (`<`), to do that the command must be executed by cmd.exe: `nsExec::Exec '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /c "c:\path\file.ext" param1 "pa r a m2 " < "c:\some.file"'`

As a final note, you should not hardcode paths, use `$ProgramFiles` and `$Instdir`, never anything starting with a drive-letter...

Comment: Now I am Using [ nsExec::Exec '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "$PROGRAMFILES\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysql.exe" -u root -D "ivms_db_clienta" < "$INSTDIR\ivms_20_64_rl_channel_group.sql"']  But it is still not working..How can I check error returned by the function  nsExec::Exec?

Comment: I believe it pushes the exit code to the stack, try Pop $0 + DetailPrint $0

Comment: The nsExec::Exec returns 1..What does it means?

Comment: "error" means nsExec failed, any other value is the exit code of the child process and there 0 usually means success and anything else is a failure. Have you tried nsExec::ExecToLog  to see what cmd.exe prints?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this path is wrong `D:\IVMS_client\ivms.sql`. You should replace it with `$INSTDIR\ivms.sql`